# how to make radio button and checkbox work together

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make a radio button filter and a check box filter work together? currently with the radio filter I already create a variable with the page shown in order to make it work together with a text filter but now I also need to use an additional filter

HTML

```
                <input id="sito" class="find" name="txt" placeholder="CLIENTE" type="text" size=15 >
                <input id="IP" class="find" name="txt" placeholder="INDIRIZZO IP" type="text" size=15>
                <input id = 'all' class = "filter" type="radio" value="All" checked name="test"><label>All</label>
                <input id = 'prod' class = "filter" type="radio" value="PROD" name="test"><label>PROD</label>
                <input id = 'test' class = "filter"type="radio" value="TEST" name="test"><label>TEST</label>
                <input id="check-naz" type="checkbox" class = "filter check" value="NAZ" name="test"><label>NAZIONALI</label>
                <input id="check-est" type="checkbox" class = "filter check" value="EST" name="test"><label>ESTERI</label>
     <div id="elenco">
                <div class="cliente naz"  value="PROD">
                    cliente
                    <div class="desc" >
                            scommettendo prod <br>
                        
        
                    </div>
                    <div class="funzioni">
                        <span>
                         <span>INDIRIZZI IP</span>
                        </span>
                        <button type="button" onclick="managerScomP(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('manager'))" id="m1">manager</button>
                         <button type="button" onclick="reloadmemScommP(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('reload'), 'resultScommP')" id="r1">reload</button>
                         <br>
                       
                        <ul>
                            <li class="version"><button type="button" onclick="UpVersioneT(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('versione')+'/upgradeVersion','upVersionScommP')" class="rs1">UpVersione</button><div class="resultVersion" id="upVersionScommP">Risultato</div></li>
                            <li><button type="button" onclick="rilascio(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('versione')+'/upgradeVersion?isRelease=1 ','rilascio-scommettendo-P')" class="rs1 rilascio">Rilascio</button><div class="resultVersion" id="rilascio-scommettendo-P">Risultato</div></li>                        <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('reload')[0]+'/XPayments/reload','resultScommP0')" class="rs1">10.38.0.21</button><div class="result" id="resultScommP0">Risultato</div></li>
                            <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('reload')[1]+'/XPayments/reload','resultScommP1')" class="rs1"></button><div class="result"  id="resultScommP1">Risultato</div></li>
                            <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('reload')[2]+'/XPayments/reload','resultScommP2')" class="rs1"></button><div class="result" id="resultScommP2">Risultato</div></li>
        
                          </ul>
        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cliente estero" value="PROD">
                    cliente
                    <div class="desc">
                        betafrik prod <br>
                       
            
                    </div>
                    <div class="funzioni">
                         <span>INDIRIZZI IP</span>
                        <button type="button" onclick="managerScomP(clienti.get('betafrik').get('betafrik prod').get('manager'))" id="m1">manager</button>
                        <button type="button" onclick="reloadmemScommP(clienti.get('betafrik').get('betafrik prod').get('reload'),'resultBetafrikP')" id="r1">reload</button>
                        <br>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="version"><button type="button" onclick="UpVersioneT(clienti.get('betafrik').get('betafrik prod').get('versione') + '/upgradeVersion','UpVersioneBetafrikP')" class="rs1">UpVersione</button><div class="resultVersion" id="UpVersioneBetafrikP">Risultato</div></li>
                            <li><button type="button" onclick="rilascio(clienti.get('betafrik').get('betafrik prod').get('versione')+'/upgradeVersion?isRelease=1 ','rilascio-betafrik-P')" class="rs1 rilascio">Rilascio</button><div class="resultVersion" id="rilascio-betafrik-P">Risultato</div></li>
                            <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('betafrik').get('betafrik prod').get('reload')[0] +'/XPayments/reload','resultBetafrikP0')" class="rs1"></button><div class="result" id="resultBetafr

ikP0">Risultato</div></li>
                        <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('betafrik').get('betafrik prod').get('reload')[1] +'/XPayments/reload','resultBetafrikP1')" class="rs1"></button><div class="result" id="resultBetafrikP1">Risultato</div></li>
                    </ul>
        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    var dom = $('#elenco .cliente'); 
    $('input[name="test"]').on('change', function(a, b) {
    value1 = this.value;
    console.log(value1)
    $('#elenco .cliente').hide();
    if (value1 == 'All') {
        $('#elenco .cliente').show();
        dom = $('#elenco .cliente');
        $('#sito').val('') 
        $('#IP').val('') 
    }
    if (value1 == 'PROD') {
        $('#elenco .cliente[value="PROD"]').show();
        dom = $('#elenco .cliente[value="PROD"]'); 
    }
    if (value1 == 'TEST') {
        $('#elenco .cliente[value="TEST"]').show();
        dom = $('#elenco .cliente[value="TEST"]'); 
    }
    if ($('#check-naz').is(':checked')){
        $('.naz').show();
        dom = $('.naz'); 
    }
    if ($('#check-est').is(':checked')){
        $('.estero').show();
        dom = $('.estero');
    }
    });
```

i tried doing dom.find('.naz').show() but it didn't work. at the end of everything in the dom variable there must be only the elements that are actually seen on the screen

Comment: We are missing parts of your code, where is the element with id `elenco` and also what element have class `cliente`?

Comment: Add HTML, it will help lessen the number of comments requesting further details.

Comment: I added the examples of the HTML code which otherwise repeats itself identically for all the elements present